# Why is ngModelChange emitting the previous value of input?

Tags: forms, angular, input, reactive

I have a (very) simple Angular2 component with nothing but a text field. I want it so that every time any change is made to this field, the console logs the value of the field.  IE if someone types "ABCD", the console should log: "A", "AB", "ABC", "ABCD".

However what I see happening is that the console is logging the PREVIOUS value of the field before the new input was registered. So instead, I'm getting: "", "A", "AB", "ABC".

How can I make it so that the console logs the value of the text field AFTER the new character has been entered?

Thank you very much.

My code so far:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'modal-test-form',
  template: `
    <form>
      <input name="data" placeholder="Type something" ngModel (ngModelChange)="onTextChange()"/>
    </form>
  `,
  //templateUrl: './modal-test-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-test-form.component.css']
})
export class ModalTestFormComponent{
  @ViewChild(NgForm) testForm : NgForm;

  constructor() { }

  onTextChange() {
    console.log(this.testForm.form.value);
  }

}
```

Comment: what "old value"?

Comment: @AJT_82 So what's happening right now is that console.log(this.testForm.form.value) is logging the value of the form BEFORE the new character was entered. So if I just entered "ABC", the console will only log "AB". I want it to instead log "ABC", which is the current value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your method to

```
(ngModelChange)="onTextChange($event)"
```

and in component class

```
onTextChange(val: string): any {
  console.log("updated value is --->", val);
}
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

change the method from

```
(ngModelChange)="onTextChange()"
```

according to where you console.log the value from form, I think you have written an "error" when you submitted your question (??), and actually you mean you have this method in your html:

```
(ngModelChange)="emitDataValue()"
```

But anyway, change it to:

```
(keyup)="emitDataValue()"
```

it seems to work the way you wish.